# anchors behind a divider are not clickable CSS HTML

Tags: css, html, z-index, anchor

Here is a simplified version code: The anchors on the left and right (behind the middle anchor) are not clickable. I tried using z-index to bring just the anchors in front and leave the divider in the back so that the middle anchor would still also be clickable... I think the best way to understand my problem would be to just make a quick example.html file and copy paste it in and try to click all 3 anchors (the middle anchor has line breaks so it looks like a lot of anchors but it's actually only 1)

JSFiddle link to code: http://jsfiddle.net/a9C3R/1/

Anyways, here is the code:

```
<div style='position:fixed; top:0%; left:0%; height:100%; width:100%;'>
<div style='width:850px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#333; border-left-width:thin; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#333; border-right-width:thin;padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:60px; padding-bottom:60px; height:100%; overflow:visible; background-color:#FFF;'>
<div>
<table width='100%' height='100%' style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
<td height='50%' width='120px' style='vertical-align:middle; height:50%; width:120px;'>
<div><a href=''>try to click me</a></div>
</td>
<td width='90%' style='vertical-align:middle; width:90%;'></td>
<td height='50%' width='120px' style='vertical-align:middle; height:50%; width:120px;'>
<div><a href=''>try to click me</a></div>
</td>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; height:100%; width:100%;'>
<div style='width:610px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:60px; padding-bottom:60px; height:100%; overflow:visible;'>
<center>
<a href=''><font size="+1">try<br>to<br>click<br>me<br><br><br><br><br>try<br>to<br>click<br>me<br><br><br><br><br>try<br>to<br>click<br>me<br><br><br><br><br>try<br>to<br>click<br>me<br><br><br><br><br>try<br>to<br>click<br>me<br><br><br><br><br>try<br>to<br>click<br>me<br><br><br><br><br>try<br>to<br>click<br>me<br><br><br><br><br></font></a>
</center>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, your `table` is lacking a `tbody`, you're using `font` and `center` tags (both of which are deprecated) and you're nesting `br` elements within an `a` (which may or may not be valid, but I suspect not). Have you tried to validate your pages with the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: I don't actually have breaks in the anchor in my real code, that was just for example so you can see the page scroll the way it does in my real code. I can get rid of the center tags and use just css for that but the real problem here is figuring out how to get the anchors on the left and right to be clickable. On a side note, no, I haven't tried validation yet.

Comment: Could you post a reproduction of your actual code to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to see it in action? Then we might actually see what's really going on with it. Also, try and validate: that often fixes some of the stranger errors.

Comment: That's an awesome website! I am not at liberty to share the actual code (non-disclosures) however I can repost the above code there, it works the same. Maybe that will help /: You may have to adjust the size of the resulting window... Here it is (link also added to original post) http://jsfiddle.net/a9C3R/1/

Comment: Ofcourse `<br>` in `<a>` are valid! Even `<div>` and `<h2>` etc are valid inside `<a>` in HTML5 (and will work anyway, always, in everybrowser, no matter the doctype). Validity puh! Go `<center>` and `<font>`! OMG backticks rule!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/a9C3R/2/
I have added `z-index: 1;position: relative;` to the second div and `style="position: relative;z-index: 1;"` for anchor which is coming after `<center>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute `<div>` completely overlaps your fixed `<div>`, and you can't use z-index to raise a child of your fixed `<div>` above your absolute `<div>` because z-index doesn't work like that. As far as I can see, the best you can do is to use separate fixed `<div>`s for the left and right links.

Comment: Is there anyway to vertically lock the position of a div without using position:fixed? If I make them separate divs they are all clickable but they scroll with the page and I need them to stay in 1 place.

Comment: The problem is having two `<div>`s covering the same area of the screen. If you can, try to fix the position of separate smaller `<div>`s.

Comment: Couldn't figure it out /: That makes sense but I had the div portioned over as a percent and when I do the smaller div absolutely positioned I can't get it in the same spot without making it part of a 100% width div /: I just left them scrolling with the screen for now.. I'll leave the question open in case anyone else can give it a go ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style='position:absolute; top:0%; left:0%; height:100%; width:100%;'>
```

this is what is causing the problem. its overlaying the other two links.
anyways your html sense is poor.

Comment: Yeah /: That's why I tried messing with z-index but I guess either that div or the nested div with the fixed position wouldn't allow z-index to work properly... Any suggestions?